# Auto increment of a unique varchar could cause duplicate

Tags: php, mysql

i have a php system which accepts hundreds of data everyday. im using MySQL as a database to stored all the data.

One of the main table, lets call it 'tableData', stored all the main data and have 2 primary keys. 1st primary key is an auto increment integer. 2nd primary key is the submission_num which stored a varchar value in this format (rep/yyyy/A.I.integer , eg. rep/2017/00021, rep/2017/00023, rep/2016/02345)

when a data needs to be submitted into tableData, the php will retrieve the maximum number of the submission_num and increase it by 1 and then insert the new data to tableData using the new submission_num. (eg. if the php receive rep/2017/00034 as the maximum number, it will increase the integer part by 1, which will result in a new submission num rep/2017/00035, and then stored the new data with the new submission num)

the algorithms of the PHP script looks something like this

1. Get max submission_num ,
   the query: **SELECT submission_num FROM tableData WHERE substr(submission_num,5,4) = '$curYear' ORDER BY submission_num DESC LIMIT 0, 1**
2. Increase the integer part by 1
3. Store the data

This method caused a problem. when two or more user hit the 'submit' button at the right moment. they will generate the same submission num and be saved to the database with duplicated submission num (this submission num needs to be unique)

Is there a way i could temporarily lock the table from any Select query from my PHP script?

Comment: btw, im very sorry if i informing you guys poorly. im quite bad in english

Comment: Depending on the type of the use table you would use transactions or locks. Anyway if you have/need two auto increment in one table indicates that you probably only need one of them or you might need to create a second table.

Answer (score 0):

A table has only one primary key constraint and it can have multiple unique constraints. Setting soapbox aside now.

You are having trouble because `submission_num` represents 3 distinct attributes of the table. Because you want to calculate the 3rd attribute (a subsequence over a given set of rows) at the time the row is inserted, you have a concurrency problem that is leading you to ask the question about locking the table.

What you should do instead is define the table the way it models reality and store the first component of `submission_num` as some type of code column and store the second component as an insert_date column.

Then you can calculate the 3rd "subattribute" later when you query the table. That way you do *not* have to lock the table, which is something the user facing application should never have to do.

Addendum 1

You can make the changes in a new table (including the additional year_submission_num column), populate the year_submission_num for rows whose insert date is less than 01-JAN-2017, then create a view that is a union of two sets A and B

The set A is the set of rows where year_submission_num is not null, in which you define a projected column, C, that is a concatenation of the values that it currently has.

The set B is a set of rows where year_submission_num is null, in which you write a more complicated subquery to produce C.

Then once a day, you run a batch job to update year_submission_num where it is currently null. That way, the "more complicated subquery" is not too expensive.

If you do all *that*, then you won't have to change your pages.

Comment: thanks for the brilliant suggestion. but seems like there will be too many pages need to be recode because there are quite a number of pages retrieving the data using submission_num. thanks for your explaination. much appreciate

Comment: @CatifyAuthent Check addendum 1.

Comment: thanks. that is quite complicated to understand at first but now i got it. it seems your solution take quite some time. i dont have much time since i can only modify the code and database at the client company. they dont allow remote. but i do have copy of the source code and database. will try to implement this on my localhost. if its good, then i will implement it later when i come here again. that will be 1 month from now. *sigh*

Answer (score -1):

I don't know if some query can handle this problem, but I have a simple approach. You can do checking again after you increase the integer part by 1, if there is no 2nd primary key like the result, you can store the data. And if there is 2nd primary key like the result, you can increase the interger part by 1 again. Yeah, you need loop process for this checking

Comment: Then the same problem could occur between the checking and the insert.

Comment: Even with your edit it would not work, you can still get duplicates. You can only solve that with auto increment fields, locks or transactions.

Comment: hi azis. thanks for the answer. and yes i do agree with everyone. the same problem could still occur. since i can modify the code from the clients company since i cannot access is remotely (and i may only able to come here again 1 month from now), i implemented your idea for now except that for every loop the script will sleep for a random time between 1 to 5 seconds. i believe this will decrease the chance of getting a duplicate submission num but will slow the submission process. i hold on to this solution for now